# What does the "#" symbol mean (e.g. in "# of blocks")

Tags: comments

Found e.g. in `pg_class.h` of Postgres source code:

```
/* # of blocks (not always up-to-date) */
int32       relpages BKI_DEFAULT(0);
```

Comment: `#` generally is shorthand for "number". *"Number of blocks (not always up-to-date)"* is how I would read that comment. That shorthand is, to my knowledge, a USA thing (perhaps Canada too). I don't believe UK english speakers use that.

Comment: I was trying to find a "duplicate" post of this out on english.stackexchange.com or similar. The closest I could find is [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43095/what-is-the-correct-abbreviation-for-the-word-numbers) where `#` is mentioned in the comments and confirms my "But not in the UK" thought.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, `#` means "number of".

`#` also meant "pounds", the measure of weight, so long ago you might see see "32# flour" on a bill of sale. This is why you'll often hear of `#` being called the "pound sign", which is not the same as the British pound sign, `£`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign